# Identifying first cluster of 1s of a certain size in a binary column

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe in which one of the columns is a binary column with 1s and 0s. I want to identify the first cluster of 1s of size 5 in that column(i.e., the first time 5 continuous 1s occur), and then delete all subsequent rows after the first 1 in that cluster.

I tried writing a loop that would count the 1s, and "continue" (i.e., break and start again) when it encountered a zero. However, I have not been able to write it correctly, because I'm unsure of the syntax. I'm new to Python, apologies if the following is completely wrong -

```
for i in randomstring["random"]:
    i = i+1
    if i%5 == 0:
        i.remove(i)
    elif i == 0:
        continue
```

The loop above ran without error but I'm not sure what it achieved, there was no output.

This is roughly what the dataframe looks like (without the other columns) :

1. 1
2. 0
3. 1
4. 0
5. 1
6. 1
7. 1
8. 1
9. 1

I want this -

1. 1
2. 0
3. 1
4. 0
5. 1

Answer (score 0):

If i rephrase your problem. It seems like you want to find an index.

I will propose you a way with numpy (just for personal reason).

```
#Just for the purpose of test
X=np.random.randint(0,2,100)

#TO have the index
Z=np.arange(len(X))

#Under it works only cause you have 0 and 1.
M=np.diff(X.cumsum())==0
U=X.cumsum()[1:][M]
Z=Z[1:][M]
COUNT=np.zeros(len(U))
COUNT[1:]=np.diff(U)
COUNT[0]=U[0]
#In COUNT there is the COUNT of consecutive 1
Z=Z-COUNT
#It gives you all the first index where the number of consecutive zero is 5
ANSWER=np.array(Z[COUNT==5],dtype=np.int32)
```

This is way too long :D . I try to find a better solution and will edit when i do.

First Edit : Change to use numpy diff.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't completely familiar with the indexing notations so took a while for me to figure out what you'd done. I'm now going to try and remove the subsequent rows after the first row of five continuous 1s